# Taking the urls of a google search

Tags: jquery

Is there any simple way to take all href from a google search page like the following:

```
https://www.google.gr/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=rWNxVtClOY7c-Qa46afIBA#q=R+Cran
```

I tried to use the following selector:

```
$("h3.r")
```

but it contains only an onmouse click.

Comment: what is the full HTML tag?

Comment: Try something like `document.getElementsByClassName('r')[0].childNodes[0].href;`, well, the jquery equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the `data-href` attribute of the link rather than the actual `href` attribute.

To do this without jQuery, use:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('r')[0].childNodes[0].dataset.href
```

Change the first array index to iterate through the results.